# p: datatable general question

Tags: jsf, datatable, primefaces

I am trying to show on a webpage different tables corresponding to different entity records. Say record types X,Y and Z.
According to a search perfomed on the webpage the tables to be shown should be displayed accordingly and each of them have their own particular columns.
Therefore I am trying the following as a simplified code snippet:

```
<p:dataTable id="recordTable"
             binding="#{searchBean.resultTable}"
             value="#{searchBean.resultListx}"
             var="currentRecord"
             paginator="true"
             rows="10"/>
```

Value corresponds to the list of records (X,Y or Z) and Binding corresponds to a pre-made DataTable I make on my backing bean which assembles columns accordingly to the type of record (X,Y or Z)

Question: Is this the correct way to do it? If not, can anyone light me up with an idea to make this exercise, the example is simplified to 3 types of entities, however on my practical case I can end up with the case of having to show up to 20 different tables of different types of records.

Most appreciated any tips, observations and feedback.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`<p:columns>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableDynamicColumns.jsf).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I have seen your blog [link](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/06/using-datatables.html). I cant use Columns as the different type of records have different columns, therefore with your proposal I would have to build different DataTables for each type of entity and manage their `rendered` property from my backing bean. Hope I made myself clear. In anycase I am not discarding the option of using `<p:column>`. If I took wrongly your suggestion let me know please.

Comment: You'd like to map the entity in a more common data structure like a `Map<K,V>` or write an universal mapper for this.

Comment: Yep I was thinking on creating a HashMap, containing the List of results and the structure of the DataTable, so starting from this point on, what would be the suggestion you make for having these dynamic columns? Having in the HashMap a list of Columns or the DataTable pre-assembled? Thanks in advance